# How many questions get closed, and how often are they edited or reopened?

Tags: discussion, closing, close-reasons, statistics

How many questions on Mathematics SE got closed during the last 90 days? For what reasons? How many of the closed questions were edited or reopened?

Answer (score 18):

This information is available under [10K tools](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days). However, it may be of interest to users under 10K, since many of them can vote to close or reopen.

For this reason, I copied the statistics to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/normalhuman/74tztrj8/embedded/result/), which I hope to keep updating periodically.

A summary of the current closing statistics (2015-08-29) is as follows:

- During the past 90 days, 45130 questions were asked; of them 7467 (or 16.55%) were closed. Of those, 261 were reopened (3.5% of all closed).
- Although the overall reopen rate is low, of the 892 questions that were *edited* after being closed, 172 were reopened: that is, 19.3%. (This figure may still be artificially low, since many edits do not change anything other than MathJax syntax.)
- Close reasons, and their percentage of all closed questions

  - missing context or other details (45.48%)
  - unclear what you're asking (19.41%)
  - duplicate (18.43%)
  - not about mathematics (4.65%)
  - too broad (3.42%)
  - primarily opinion-based (1.97%)
  - belongs on another site (0.87%)
  - off-topic custom reason (0.63%)
  - seeking personal advice (0.05%)

Comment: Interesting analysis, as always!

Comment: Interesting, i would have thought that the "duplicate"-percentage is much higher, considering the experiences in my favourite tags

Comment: Great. Of course this now makes one curious if the reopen rates differe by close reason. It seems natural to suspect that "missing context" and "unclear" can often be healed, whereas "duplicate" can (almost?) never

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That is correct: "unclear" and "missing context" are reopened more often than "duplicate" group. (Some duplicates are edited to refocus the question so that it's no longer a duplicate; and of course some of the closures are mistakes that are later corrected.) My post is only a summary of statistics; the full table is linked at the beginning of the post.